# angular-cli ng error after installing on a MAC

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, mean-stack

I'm trying to install the MEAN stack on my Mac Book Pro.
I'm getting an error consistently after install node and angular-cli.

when running the command 'ng help, or ng -v' I get the error:
 **"ng help
  -bash: ng: command not found"**.

Here are my specs:
node -v
v6.11.3
npm -v
3.10.10
MAC Sierria 10.12.6

I've tried several steps in forums and uninstalling and reinstalling node and npm several times.

Also, I've tried installing and uninstalling from BREW. I keep getting the same error though.

Is there a correct way to install the MEAN stack on a MAC? Specifically for the issue I'm experiencing with the angular-cli?

Also, I've set permissions to my npm folders according to this site: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you do not have `@angular/cli` installed globally. Use `-g` flag to install it globally:

```
npm i @angular/cli -g
```

to check your globally installed packages run:

```
npm ls -depth 0 -g
```

if your list is very long, you can narrow it with `grep`:

```
npm ls -depth 0 -g | grep angular
```

make sure that you have angular CLI listed there.

I personally prefer installing angular CLI locally per project and accessing it via *node_modules/.bin*:

```
node_modules/.bin/ng -v
```

Comment: BTW, which MEAN stack are you using with angular CLI? mean.io?

Comment: I guess I didn't realize that there were multiple options. I started by following the steps from this site: https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/how-to-install-the-mean-stack-on-mac-osx/19362

Comment: after running 'npm ls -depth 0 -g' I get '@angular/cli@1.4.3 npm@5.4.2'

Comment: strange, you have angular CLI locally. You also can add it to your $PATH by executing: `PATH=$PATH:\`npm root -g\`/@angular/cli/bin`. 
`npm root -g` (with back ticks) should return you global node modules location, just make sure you have '@angular/cli/bin' path within it

Answer (score 0):

Found this here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5021
Worked for me.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli

Make sure the ng path is correct
    cd ~/npm-global/bin
    ls and make sure ng exists

create .bashrc file on your home directory
    touch ~/.bashrc
    vim ~/.bashrc

Add ng as alias
    press a (enables edit mode) then type in the following
    alias ng="~/npm-global/bin/ng"
    press esc (to get out of edit mode) then :wq (in vim will save)

Temporarily Update .bashrc reference
Your terminal wont take bash updates until a restart but the following command will let you use the updates during the terminal session:
    source ~/.bashrc

Check that ng works
    ng --version
```

Comment: Seems you might need to type source ~/.bashrc each time you start terminal

Answer (score -1):

npm install -g @angular/cli

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/README.md

if you have problem with your node, you may need [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)